# Is it unsafe to use a managed library in a software?

Tags: c#, obfuscation, managed-c++

When we want to use a native shared library, we have to have the header files. So when we publish the software, others do not have the header files and they can not use the library.

But the managed library does not need any headers. Because you can simply use add reference in Visual Studio and use Object Browser to see all the classes and namespaces.

So when we publish our application with managed library, not only **others can use our library in their own project (whether it is obfuscated or not)**, but also they can decompile it and see the whole source code if it is not obfuscated.

Is it true?

How can we secure our managed library?

Comment: Like you said, you can use an `obfuscator` to scramble your source.

Comment: @Jeronvanlangen but they can still use it in their own project. Yes?

Comment: Yes, but the method/class/property names are not descriptive to what they are doing. they might be renamed to `__eeee`  etc.

Comment: @Jeronvanlangen I should be able to call my own methods from outside. So the public methods and classes are not renamed.

Comment: i'm not sure, never used it. You might do some reading here. Search the web for obfuscators and .NET

Comment: @Jeronvanlangen I have been using obfuscatos for years.

Comment: why this question is downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's perfectly safe. In practice the main impact of having users able to see (a decompiled approximation of) the workings of the library is that you sometimes get a higher quality of bug report from them.

Software companies like Microsoft manage to eke a living despite consumers being able to decompile their libraries, or indeed just read the published source.

But if you really want to prevent it then being managed does not preclude being obfuscated.

[There](http://www.gapotchenko.com/eazfuscator.net) [are](https://obfuscar.codeplex.com/) [several](http://appfuscator.com/) [obfuscators](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/smartassembly/) [available](http://aveloy.com/Products/DotRefiner.aspx), and if you really want to get in the way of your users, you can ilmerge in the library to a make a single obfuscated executable, so they can't even use the library, never mind <s>give you useful feedback</s> copy your code.

Comment: You should not refer to actual products, use catchwords.

Comment: @Jeroen van Langen, is this a new rule?

Comment: It's much more useful to refer to actual products